# How I can genarate Unique Random number and store in mysql table in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, random

I want to develop an Spring boot web application where I can generate sets of number and store in a table.
For example

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/testInteger")
    public String genint(com.randomdata.entity.Random random) {
        
        
        int intRange;
        try {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                intRange = generateRandomIntIntRange(1000, 10000);
                String string = Integer.toString(intRange);
                random.setRandomNumber(string);
                randomDao.save(random);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return "index";
        
    }
```

This is my random number generating method.

```
public static int generateRandomIntIntRange(int min, int max) {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        
    }
```

But it's can save 1 number in db table and others showing

Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=? 
Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=? 
Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=? 
Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=? 
Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=? 
Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=? 
Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=? 
Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=? 
Hibernate: update random set random_number=? where id=?

Of course, I missed something. but I cannot find yet.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "But it's can save 1 number in db table and others showing"? It's not clear how it's phrased.

Comment: This script has a 10 iteration request where it can generate and insert 1 unique number but the other 9 unique easily generate but not insert in the table I can't track why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seen to be that you are using the same object every time you save a random number so you are updating that same object every time. You should try creating a new object like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  intRange = generateRandomIntIntRange(1000, 10000);
  String string = Integer.toString(intRange);
  random = new com.randomdata.entity.Random();
  random.setRandomNumber(string);
  randomDao.save(random);
}
```

Comment: Well, it won't be unique, you'll get collision. See https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/ for details